# Objective-C Social Networking General Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, social-networking

I've been developing application for Iphone and now I want to try to create appplication like social bookmarking but I didn't really find any help on the net. 
I will have a create a login/pass, retrieve data and display them.
So I want to know what do I have to use to implement all of that for any social bookmarking website. 
If you have suggestion, idea, tutorial, you are welcome.

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Most of the major social networking sites have API's for coding against their services, for instance [Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone) and [Twitter](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/).

I'm sure there are other API's available, so it's just a matter og Googling for them using something like " *social-network-name* API developer" as serch criteria.

Claus

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to integrate with an existing one?

Comment: sorry I didn't explain myself verywell, I try to know the way to connect to social networking website, like Twitter, facebook... also not famous one. I just want to know where and how to begin.